# Add spacing between two props

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to use a bootstrap button for my project and I have some trouble figuring out how to personalize the style of the button depending on the use.

In this particular case I'd like to add an icon next to the connection button and manage the spacing between the text and my icon.

My button component is:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Bouton = styled(Button)`
height: max-content;
width: max-content;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
align-items: center;

&{font-size: 1.5em;
outline:none;
}
&:focus{
  box-shadow: none;
}`;

function StyledButton(props) {

  return (
    <Bouton variant="outline-dark">{props.icon} {props.text}</Bouton>
  )
}

export default StyledButton;
```

My connection button code is:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import StyledButton from '../StyledBouton';
import React from 'react';
import { FaUserCircle } from 'react-icons/fa'

const connectionText = 'Se connecter';
const ConnectionButton = styled(StyledButton)`
  margin-left: auto;
    &::before{
    }
    `;
const ConnectionItemWrapper = styled.div`
  margin-left: auto;
`

function ConnectionItem() {


  return (
    <ConnectionItemWrapper className='connection-item0'>
      <ConnectionButton className="connection-item" icon ={<FaUserCircle />} text={connectionText}> </ConnectionButton>
    </ConnectionItemWrapper>
  );

}

export default ConnectionItem;
```

I am able to add my icon next to my text but I can't change the width of my connection component without editing all my button's style. How am I suppose to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in different way

1. `<Bouton variant="outline-dark">{props.icon}&nbsp;&nbsp;{props.text}</Bouton>`
2. 

```
const Bouton = styled(Button)'

....

display: flex;
justify-content: center;
gap: 4px;

}';
```

Comment: thank you that's exactly what I wanted to do

Answer (score 0):

Add `gap: 8px` or whatever within your `Styled Button` styles

Comment: thank you that was exaclty what I wanted. I've restarted my app and it worked fine

Comment: Glad to be helpful!